# Exclude kerberos dependency from mongodb in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, npm, kerberos

I have a node app that has mongodb as a dependency. From what I can tell, mongodb is dependent on kerberos stuff but as far as I'm aware I don't need it. This causes problems because when I try to deploy my app to aws beanstalk it chokes and barfs all over the place because of the system dependency. Is it possible to exclude that dependency in my `package.json`?

```
> kerberos@0.0.17 install /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
  > (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

  make: Entering directory `/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/build'
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
  In file included from ../lib/kerberos.cc:1:0:
  ../lib/kerberos.h:5:27: fatal error: gssapi/gssapi.h: No such file or directory
   #include <gssapi/gssapi.h>
                             ^
  compilation terminated.
  make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o] Error 1
  make: Leaving directory `/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  gyp ERR! build error 
  gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
  gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
  gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
  gyp ERR! System Linux 4.1.10-17.31.amzn1.x86_64
  gyp ERR! command "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
  gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
  gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.1
  gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
  gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can read [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)

> The kerberos package is a C++ extension that requires a build environment to be installed on your system. **You must be able to build node.js itself to be able to compile and install the kerberos module**. Furthermore the kerberos module requires the MIT Kerberos package to correctly compile on UNIX operating systems. Consult your UNIX operation system package manager what libraries to install.

A possible solution is to install the package **libkrb5-dev** (Debian/Ubuntu) or **krb5-devel** (CentOS) on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a problem with node version. I had the same problem with kerberos. Note that EB uses node 4.x by default. Go to the software configuration page and change the environment.